# Is there in C++ already some class which print to cout but can be off when some macro is not defined (for example DEBUG)?

Tags: c++

Is there in C++ already some class which print to cout but can be off when some macro is not defined (for example DEBUG) ?

I can do like

```
#ifdef DEBUG
std::cout<<"some data"<<"new log<<"\n";
#endif
```

but is there already overridden operator<< so this be compressed on just one line

Comment: Generally if you do this you want the statement to be wrapped in a macro too, so that the parameters are not needlessly evaluated when the output is disabled. There's no way to do that with just an operator overload.

Comment: @MarkRansom The compiler will probably be able to optimize it away easily and im sure that a more advanced solution using constexpr and/or templates could also avoid it without macros

Answer (score 4):

You can easily make your own:

```
namespace mystd
{
   struct X {
       template<typename T>
       X& operator << (const T& x)
       {
       #ifdef DEBUG
           std::cout << x;
       #endif
           return *this;
       }
   } cout;
}
```

and write

```
mystd::cout << "   " << "   ";
```

Comment: will e.g. functions (`mystd::cout << "lala " << foo();`) be called if DEBUG is not defined? i'm not sure, but since shift operator precedence is left to right i would say yes.

Comment: @itwasntpete yes, but it's a no-op in this case.

Comment: whops, my sence was totaly wrong :( sorry for that. i meant will it be called if DEBUG *is* defined and i asume not because of the precendence. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple answere: No, but you can implement this logic easily.

More advanced logging frameworks will actually define a bigger set of logging levels and decide to log based on the current level and the level of the message.

For an example you could take a look at the Poco framework: http://pocoproject.org/slides/110-Logging.pdf

They also offer an `std::ostream` wrapper around their logging framework

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::ostream` state flags to conditionally disable output. A corresponding use code look like this:

```
std::cout << log << "hello, ";
std::cout << "world\n";
```

The implementation which enables/disables output when using `log` could be something like the code below: `log` is actually constructing an objects which will disable the output if `DEBUG` is not defined when inserted into a stream by setting the stream flag `std::ios_base::failbit`. Its destructor will restore the stream state if the state got changed. Since a stream is used, you can also pass the stream object to a function and it will conditionally write output:

```
extern void f(std::ostream&);
f(std::cout << log);
```

Of course, the objects also work with other `std::ostream` objects, not just `std::cout`.

```
#ifndef SIMPLE_LOG
#define SIMPLE_LOG

#include <ostream>

class log_enabled
{
    mutable std::ostream*          stream;
    mutable std::ios_base::iostate state;
    bool                           logging;
public:
    log_enabled(bool l)
        : stream(0)
        , state()
        , logging(l) {
    }
    ~log_enabled() {
        if (stream) {
            stream->clear(this->state);
        }
    }
    std::ostream& setup(std::ostream& out) const {
        if (!logging) {
            this->stream = &out;
            this->state = out.rdstate();
            out.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
        return out;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, log_enabled const& log) {
    return log.setup(out);
}

#  ifdef DEBUG
#    define log log_enabled(true)
#  else
#    define log log_enabled(false)
#  endif

#endif
```

Comment: @itwasntpete: When `DEBUG` is defined, `log_enabled` hold a `logging` member which is `true`, i.e., the condition in `setup()` (i.e., `!logging`) is `false` and the output is not disabled. I think the logic is the correct way around (and that's also what the tests confirmed...).

Comment: ahh, ok i see. the word order was confusing me :)